# Reshaping dataframe - two columns from correlation variables

Tags: r, aggregate, reshape

I have the below df

```
    var1 var2 Freq
1    a    b   10
2    b    a    5
3    b    d   10
```

created from

```
help <- data.frame(var1 = c("a", "b", "b"), var2 = c("b", "a", "d"), Freq = c(10, 5, 10))
```

ab correlation is the same as ba, and I am hoping to combine them into one row to look like

```
   var1 var2 Freq
1    a    b   15
2    b    d   10
```

any thoughts?

Comment: By using `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`, you can change `var1=pmin(var1,var2)` and `var2=pmax(var1,var2)`, after which aggregation should be straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
setNames(aggregate(help$Freq, as.data.frame(t(apply(help[-3], 1, sort))), sum), 
         names(help))

#   var1 var2 Freq
# 1    a    b   15
# 2    b    d   10
```

Comment: Thanks, Sven. Can you explain what the help[-3] means?

Comment: @bpace The command `help[-3]` is an example of negative indexing. It returns all columns of `help` except the third one.

Answer (score 0):

In base R :

```
do.call(rbind,
by(dat,rowSums(sapply(dat[,c("var1","var2")],as.integer)),
   function(x)data.frame(x[1,c("var1","var2")],
                         Freq= sum(x[,"Freq"]))))

  var1 var2 Freq
3    a    b   15
5    b    d   10
```

I create first a grouping variable by summing the integer representation of your columns. Then performing the sum of frequencies by group. Finally bind the result to get a new data.frame.